# How cab I get MAC address of a selected device in pcap.net

Tags: c#, network-programming, pcap.net

How can I get MAC address of a selected LivePacketDevice in pcap.net?

```
var allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;
LivePacketDevice dev = allDevices[0];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `LivePacketDeviceExtensions` static method:

```
public static MacAddress GetMacAddress(this LivePacketDevice livePacketDevice)
```

It is defined in `PcapDotNet.Core.Extensions` Assembly in the `PcapDotNet.Core.Extensions` namespace.